# How to check the checkbox of Adobe Installer with the Aplescript?

Tags: applescript

am trying to Install Adobe Flash Player, I want to check the check box and need to click on Install button, Whem am trying to get the entire contents of window thru UIElementInspector, am unable to get the contents of checkbox and Install buttons..

I just tried myself with the below script to click the checkbox, but did not succeed, error saying unable to get the checkbox.. Pls suggest how to check..

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Flash Player Install Manager"
        set frontmost to true

        click the checkbox "I have read and agree to the terms of the Flash Player License Agreement" of window "Adobe Flash Player 11.5 Installer."

    end tell
end tell
```

Pls check the below link to view the image of the Adobe Flash Player Installer.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yzyBTrvi94QxjlEAlcbudOBpXiTGPEI2LA3D1iEo8Gw/ edit

Answer (score 1):

Download this S/w:

http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/downloads/UIBrowser222.dmg

Install it.

You can simply use this tool to read the name of checkboxes and all.

For ex: if you attach a application which is having a window and a checkbox within it you can check that checkbox simply by following script:

```
tell aplication "system events"
   click checkbox 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Just remember to keep the window on front most amongst other windows.

You can attach your process by clicking target pop-up button present in the UI Browser app.

Then click on Switch to screen reader option.

Now you can just see the names of the buttons, controls, checkbo

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. I was using UI browser trial version earlier.. now its expired.. any ways to get the keys??

Comment: Hahaha :-) Thats easy now :-) Just right click on the application and goto info.plist. Check for the bundle identifier there. Just remember that bundler identifier. then goto ~/Library/Preferences and delete that perticular plist file whose name starts with the UI browser's bundle idetier. Just simple as that :-)

Comment: You should be able to do it . Tell me the version of the UI browser and Mac OS X that you are using.